# How to remove remote notification from notification center after a minute passed?

Tags: ios, remote-notifications

I am searching for a solution for how to accomplish above, no success so far.

**The way it should work:**

Notification arrives to device, and after a minute it deletes itself.

**What I have already tried:**

Sent a silent and a non-silent (*content_available: true / false*) notification to receiver with the previous notification ID, which triggered a method, that deleted the whole notification center's delivered notifications. The problem is it does not called when the app is in terminated state, only when the app is in the background / foreground / suspended.

Is there a legitimate way, to pull this off? I'm open for suggestions and ideas! Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can have a service that returns the ID's of dispatched notifications. Run this service as soon as the app enters foreground, and using the data delete the notifications from the center.

Comment: No, there is no way to achieve this when your app is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the requirement you are checking out is not achievable. When app is terminated, you have no control over notifications area.